# Is RxAndroid could replace the role of IntentService?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-intentservice

Is RxAndroid could replace the role of IntentService ?
I need to start from activity, but leaving activity the service continues its job. I steel need to continue interaction from background thread with UI thread ,(but not exactly for specified Activity, as the completion of separate thread could coincide with any Activity), and I need to start another thread for main thread, Is it possible to implement all these interactions using  RXAndroid? any advise or sample that could help me, could be great job for me.

Comment: While `Rx` stuff can help with asynchronous work, a `Service` has larger ramifications than that. The point behind using a `Service`, such as an `IntentService`, is to let the OS know that you are doing work for the user, and so Android should keep your process around a little longer, even when it goes into the background from a UI standpoint. I do not know if RxAndroid incorporates any services into it that you could use for this. If your use case does not need this feature of a `Service`, then the correct comparison would be RxAndroid to something like an `AsyncTask`.